# how to update only one datagridview column from database

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridiview control with one image column connected to an sql database. I would like to change pictures at the runtime, write to database and at the same time retrieve the image from database to show on datagridview cell. right now, when I click on image cell, I got a pop up to browser to image, write to database but I can't retrieve just the updated image without getting everything else. any idea on how to do this ? the code below load the whole table
thanks a lot

```
 Public Sub GetImagesFromDatabase()
    Try
        'Initialize SQL Server connection.
        _Connection.Open()

        'Initialize SQL adapter.
        Dim ADAP As New SqlDataAdapter("Select pic from tblimgData", _Connection)

        'Initialize Dataset.
        Dim DS As New DataSet()

        'Fill dataset with ImagesStore table.
        ADAP.Fill(DS, "tblimgData")


        DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables("tblimgData")
        _Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to know the Primary Key of your table and retrieve also that column.

Comment: Hopefully u have an identity column, if so return that column in your select as@Steve has mentioned.

Comment: Thats OK but what if the datagridview have more then one image column ?

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

```
Public Sub GetImagesFromDatabase()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, cn)' sql: the sql query string
' cn : Initialized SQL Server connection.
    Try

        cmd.Connection.Open()
        dim dr as SqlDataReader
dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()
while not read
  DataGridView1.rows(index).cells(index) = dr.getstring()
  ADAP.Fill(DS,dr.getstring())
end while

        _Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

End Sub